# Coalescing NSNotifications of the same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotifications

I am trying to merge `NSNotifications` that happens within a short amount of time. I tried the following:

```
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:kMyNotificationName object:self]postingStyle:NSPostWhenIdle coalesceMask:NSNotificationCoalescingOnName forModes:nil];
```

It looks like my *notifications* are nicely merged but they are sent only when a UI interaction happens. For example, I enqueue many *notifications* but they are fired only when I touch the tableView of my current view controller. How to fire them even though there is no UI interaction?

**Edit**
I tried different posting style : NSPostNow (or NSPostASAP) doesn't do what I need (my notifications are not merged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the edit**

I have no experience with this mechanism (thanks for making me discover it ;)), but I think your are looking for the posting style `NSPostNow`.

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000220-DontLinkElementID_2):

> **NSPostNow**
>
> The notification is posted immediately after coalescing.

So your code may look like this:

```
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:kMyNotificationName object:self] postingStyle:NSPostNow coalesceMask:NSNotificationCoalescingOnName forModes:nil];
```

**EDIT**: After reading the docs more thoroughly, (in particular [NotificationQueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationQueues.html) and [RunLoopManagement](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW12)), I think your issue is that your are posting notifications only in default run loop mode.

From my understanding and the tests I made, you should use the posting style **`NSPostingASAP`** (`NSPostingNow` is in fact equivalent to calling `postNotification` on the `NSNotificationCenter`, that is not what you want) and post for all common run loop modes (ie. **`NSRunLoopCommonModes`**).

This will ask the queue to post notification ASAP, even during the `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` loop mode ([included in `NSRunLoopCommonModes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW12)).

```
[[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:kMyNotificationName object:self] postingStyle:NSPostASAP coalesceMask:NSNotificationCoalescingOnName forModes:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: I already tried that posting style but my notifications are not merged anymore with this posting style. In my case I can have up to 4 notifications that needs to be merged. My guess is that NSPostNow post a notification right after 2 notifications are merged. I need to merge more than 2 notifications (PS: nice to see an EPITA student here !)

Comment: Ok it works :) Thanks. The downside of this method is that it might take some time before the merged notification gets fired. Not really the best idea when the UI needs to be updated with a notification.